# Japanese datetime format after 1/5/2019

Tags: c#, datetime, cjk

I need to format `DateTime` value to string in Japanese. The problem is: After 1/5/2019 Japan has a new king, so it must be 令和元年05月01日. But when I use my code, the result is 平成31年05月01日

```
public static string GetTextDateJapan(DateTime date)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    JapaneseCalendar calendarJp = new System.Globalization.JapaneseCalendar();
    CultureInfo cultureJp = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ja-JP", false);
    cultureJp.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = calendarJp;
    result = date.ToString("ggyy年MM月dd日", cultureJp);
    return result;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string strDate = GetTextDateJapan(DateTime.Now);           
    Console.WriteLine(strDate );
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Just making sure you've followed https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4497197/how-to-prepare-windows-and-office-for-the-may-2019-japan-era-change before trying this code (at very least have Win8/10 with all latest updates).

Comment: Japan doesn't have a *king* but an **emperor**

Comment: date is param and "gg" is format only for japan format, it can be king's name

Comment: It show same on my system may be Microsoft need to update date library

Comment: Look at this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/handling-a-new-era-in-the-japanese-calendar-in-net/

Answer (score 3):

I think you need new Japanese era Windows updates - KB4469068

A new Japanese era and its associated calendar begin on May 1, 2019.

This article has all the links related to new dates

https://insbhat.blogspot.com/2019/05/japanese-new-era-date.html

For date to work as you want you need to update

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ae/help/4469068/summary-of-new-japanese-era-updates-kb4469068

Prepare for new era japanese date

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/japanese-era-change

Comment: If this has solved your problem then mark my answer as correct